# Quick and dirty way to save the program state in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, serialization

I have a game I'm writing that I need to debug a certain feature of. The problem with this game is that currently, there is no way to begin from a "running game" which mean that every time I want to test certain features, I need to do the setup (which takes 2-3 minutes every time)

To make things worse, the game randomizes the objects therefore I may not see them in the game for a while. I have turned off the randomization for debugging purposes however unfortunately doing so breaks a lot of other parts of the game.

Therefore, I was wondering if (like C) there is a way to dump the application state to the hard drive and load it again later.

I'm aware that there is serialization in the C#, however since being able to load a "save game" wouldn't be available in the final release version I'd prefer an easier way if possible.

Thanks

Comment: What part of utilizing the serialization functionality provided by the .NET Framework is difficult? I'm not sure I could imagine an easier way of doing this...

Comment: It's not that is hard, it's the fact that to serialize I need to define get/sets for all my fields which is a pain this late in the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about saving a full dump, doubt that it is possible, but the randomization problem is usually solved by seeding the (pseudo) random number generator with the same number every time -- this will ensure that your random number sequence is the same every time.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be right to mark this as the answer to my question however this does solve the randomization issue, I'm not sure how I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding saving state -- have you considered recording all keyboard/mouse events so that they can be replayed?  This is a lot of work, but the results are often fun and invaluable in debugging.  Also a nice way to record a demo.